# How to use Network-HTTP-Conduit applyBasicAuth

Tags: haskell, http-conduit

I want to use Basic Authentication from [`Network.HTTP.Conduit`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit) and cannot make it work.

From the documentation...

```
applyBasicAuth :: ByteString -> ByteString -> Request m -> Request mSource
```

Add a Basic Auth header (with the specified user name and password) to the given Request. Ignore error handling:

> applyBasicAuth user pass $ fromJust $ parseUrl url

But when I try to implement that in a simple "Hello World" example:

```
import Data.ByteString as B

import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import Network.Socket

main :: IO ()
main = withSocketsDo $ do
  req <- applyBasicAuth user pass $ fromJust $ parseUrl "http://www.oracle.com"
  response <- withManager $ httpLbs req
  B.putStrLn $ responseBody response
  where
    user = B.pack "scott"
    pass = B.pack "tiger"
```

Compilation fails with: **Not in scope: fromJust**

```
make fromJust.exe && ./fromJust.exe
ghc --make fromJust.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( fromJust.hs, fromJust.o )

fromJust.hs:16:37: Not in scope: `fromJust'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Not in scope: fromJust" means that the compiler cannot find `fromJust`, since it's not defined in your module, or in any of your imported modules (including the Prelude, which is imported automatically by default).

You need to import it yourself from the correct module. You can [find out which one using Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=fromJust).

In this case, you need to import [`Data.Maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Maybe.html).

Comment: It works, but in previous exercises, I never imported Data.Maybe and could use the Maybe type.

Comment: @Chris: The `Maybe` type is also exported by the Prelude, which is why you didn't have to import anything (since the Prelude is imported by default). However, not all of the utility functions for working with `Maybe` are in the Prelude. It's the same thing for e.g. list functions. The most common ones are in the Prelude, the rest are in `Data.List`.